# Conversion counters (n) to n rows hive

Tags: hive

How can I accomplish the following transformation in the hive.

```
<some string> n (Int) => n rows.

<some string>
<some string>
<some string>
....
<some string>
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the 'numeric_range' UDTF in Brickhouse ( http://github.com/klout/brickhouse )

```
SELECT some_string,
       idx
FROM my_table
LATERAL VIEW numeric_range( n ) nidx as idx;
```

This will output an integer from 0 to n -1,  and is primarily used for accessing arrays.